# In-line row editing with Grid.MVC

Tags: grid.mvc

Is it possible to do in-line row edit (double click on a row and edit it) in Grid.MVC. The documentation is [here](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: what you did, just post here

Comment: Currently, I have an edit button on each row which would then open a pop-up to edit the records. Now I need to do the editing inline, meaning when I double click on the row, I should be able to edit the row without using popup.

Comment: yes you can, just replace the row elements(<td></td>) to the input elements and change edit button to save button using javascript, after clicking save using ajax save the inputted data for that particularrow based on some unique id and in success response again replace the input elements to the row elements(<td></td>)

Comment: any working example? because I have tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: post your html here